# Mongoid 4: like query on integer column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid4

I need a mongoid search like query with **INTEGER COLUMN**. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobile LIKE '%9980%';
```

Here is the my model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  ##
  # Columns
  field :name,                      type: String
  field :mobile,                    type: Integer
end
```

I already tried following examples. But no luck :(

```
User.where(:$where => "/^#{params[:mobile]}/")
User.any_of({mobile: /.*#{params[:mobile]}.*/i})
User.where(mobile: /8801/))
```

How to write it with mongoid?

Comment: Mobile? Are you storing a phone number as a number?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
User.where(mobile: /.*#{params[:mobile]}.*/i)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but it's not work. I think the issue is `mobile` column is an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

```
users = User.where(:$where => "/^#{params[:mobile]}/.test(this.mobile)")
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.where(:mobile => /\d*{params[:mobile]}\d*/)`

Like function in Mongoid is just instead the arguement of `where` to `regexp`

Comment: Hello, Thank you for trying to help me. I run your code but it's not work. Here is the command: `User.where(:mobile => /\d*8801\d*/).length`. It shows me 0. But in my db it's 32.

Comment: Oh sorry, I ignore that `mobile` field is a `Integer`, `regexp` may only works with `String` filed. Why the `mobile` field use a integer type, if a mobile is `18892887374`, its so big for a integer.

Comment: Because in my country's mobile number consists of 8 characters. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Use the ruby way `User.all.select {|u| u.mobile.to_s.include?(params[:mobile])}`

Comment: Hmm, it will reduce my load time :(

Comment: Yes, it may be a bit slow, will you consider change mobile field to string to use native function?

Comment: Woohoo. I just make it work: `users = User.where(:$where => "/^#{params[:mobile]}/.test(this.mobile)")`