# MongoID Like query on embedded model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have User model **embeds_one :profile** and Profile model has name. I need to run **LIKE query** on profile name. I tried below as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739745/mongoid-4-like-query-on-integer-column)

```
User.where("profile.name" => "/.*Senthil.*/")
```

But above solution not working. I tried lot of stock overflow answers , but no luck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Screenshot : I am very sure , there is matching record.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This finds all people with the name **senthil** (first OR last).

```
User.where("profile.name" => /.*senthil.*/i )
```

Here `i` used to make the query **case insensitive**.

Comment: this is not equivalent to what he's trying to do because it matches any case.

Comment: Yes it is, since person name checking should always be case insensitive.

Comment: how to embed verifiable in it... ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to remove the quotes, otherwise the engine will try to match the string exactly, instead of as regex

edit: The correct regexp would be

`User.where("profile.name" => /.*Senthil.*/)`